# How to remove double quotes from string

Tags: go

I have a string that I'm pulling from a website, however, it has double quotes surrounding it and I'm trying to remove them. The string is for example:

`"        54%"`

I've tried:

`strings.Trim(s[0], "\"")`

But it's not removing the quotes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you printing or otherwise communicating the string? (In other words, where do you see `"        54%"`?)

Comment: What makes you think there's quotes on the string?

Comment: I'm printing it out as so: `fmt.Println(strings.Trim(s[0], "\""))`

Comment: Please be in front of the code and copy it verbatim, don’t retype. The output too. (If it’s retyped, very hard to know if the `"` is actually `”`.)

Answer (score 5):

```
s := "\"  hello\""

fmt.Println("Without trim: " + s) 
// Without trim: "  hello"

fmt.Println("Trim double quotes: " + strings.Trim(s, "\"")) 
// Trim double quotes:   hello
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/0I2BtS6b_mO

Comment: It for whatever reason isn't stripping the quotes. Also it's an array so I can't just use `s`, gives me the following error `cannot use s (type []string) as type string in argument to strings.Trim`

Answer (score 0):

Please give working code. Things that could be wrong:

- You're using s[0] that means the first byte of s, did you mean to use s or is this an array of strings?
- Your string may have trailing or leading whitespace
- Your string may use smart quotes

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, perhaps you are misinterpreting some printed results or storing the wrong value?

```
ss := []string{"foo", `""`, `"bar"`, `"        54%"`}
for _, s := range ss {
  t := strings.Trim(s, `"`)
  fmt.Printf("OK:    [%s] --> [%s]\n", s, t)
}
// OK:    [foo] --> [foo]
// OK:    [""] --> []
// OK:    ["bar"] --> [bar]
// OK:    ["        54%"] --> [        54%]
//         │           │       │         │
// quotes ─┴───────────┘       │         │
// no quotes ──────────────────┴─────────┘
```